# How to Re-Initialize MONO.mono_load_runtime_and_bcl

Tags: mono, webassembly

After mono load runtime, We have set of new dlls, which needs to be loaded on demand, is there are a way to re-initialize MONO.mono_load_runtime_and_bcl or destroy and re-load again?